# retrieving Column cells value from datagridview C#

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to solve this. I want to  calculate in datagridview

Column 3 like this

[image]

using C#

Comment: Please add more details, like paste a portion of code you are using to do the calculation.

Comment: **bold** 'code'
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Customers");
DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
workCol.AllowDBNull = true; 
workCol.Unique = false;
DataRow workRow; 
workTable.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(Double));
workTable.Columns.Add("Column 2", typeof(Double));
workRow = workTable.NewRow();
workRow[0] = Convert.ToInt32(dr[7].ToString());
workRow[1] = Convert.ToDouble(Column 1.ToString());
workRow[2] = Convert.ToDouble(Column 2.ToString());

Comment: workTable.Rows.Add(workRow);
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr1 in workRow.Table.Rows)
{sum1 += Convert.ToInt32(dr1["Column 1"]);
sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(dr1["Column 2"]);
}**bold** 'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
            int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
```

Comment: it's not allowed to me to use datagrideview

Comment: so i try to use DataTable                                                                                                                                                                                                                     but i can't  use datatable like datagrideview

Answer (score 0):

To calculate values from you datagridview, you can do several approaches

For example, you can retrieve by rows then reference the column of the cell by index or column name. 
For example, adding values in "Column 3" would be:

```
var rows = dataGridView1.rows;
double sum = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
 {
   sum += (double)row.Cells["Column 3"].Value;
 }
```

**EDIT:**
If you're using DataTable (which I presume from your comments) to get individual cell data, you can either reference the row first then adding an index based on the column, or you can create a temp row, then get the value using the column. The records or values within a DataTable are basically just collection of rows.

Example:

```
int col3 = workTable.Columns.IndexOf("Column 3") -1;
double amount = Convert.ToDouble(workTable.Rows[1][col3]); // 1st value in column 3
```

OR (extended for clarity)

```
DataRow row1 = workTable.Rows[1];
double amount = Convert.ToDouble(row1[col3]);
```

If you need to transpose values into a DataGridView, you can just set the DataSource property of a DataGridView instance i.e.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = newFilledTable;
```